# Loading shared libraries while running program in c instead of linking

Tags: c

I want to load a library inside my app instead of linking it while compiling .I mean I do'nt want to link it with "-lxzy" while compiling .

sth like load_library("xyz"); or .... . how may I do that ?

Comment: [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but done differently depending on platform.

On POSIX systems, like Linux and OSX, you can use [`dlopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlopen.html) to open a dynamic library (files typically ending in `.so`), and [`dlsym`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dlsym.html) to find symbols (e.g. functions) in the libraries.

For Windows, use the [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to load a DLL, and [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a function pointer.

Comment: I want to do that on UNIX based OS

Comment: @alireza7991 Those are POSIX.